# Jooq INSERT on duplicate key UPDATE

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

Trying to use "jooq" to work with db (MySQL).
It looks like nice, but as sql query more complex jooq construction more obscure.

Is anybody know what code should I write to get SQL-analog for:

```sql
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, counter) VALUES (123, abc, 10), (124, cde, 20)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter = counter + VALUES(counter);
```

Answer (score 1):

This particular vendor-specific syntax is not yet supported by jOOQ 3.2. It is on the long-term roadmap as [#2134](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2134)

Comment: If I will use manual way to build SQL query, how can I use dslContext to return generated values after insert? Now I use StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO ...; dslContext.query(queryBuilder.toString());

Comment: @user2602807: Good point, that's currently not supported, unfortunately. I have registered another feature request for this: [#2943](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2943)